# how to read a plain text file stored at a server link in my javascript code

Tags: javascript

I have a plain text file stored at somewhere at a server to which i have the link.
Now i want to read the file contents in a string var in my javascript code.
Now I have written the code but does not know how to read the contents of the file.

I want to display the contents of the file in an alert box to the user, Can you please help.

```
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
{
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
    {

                                                          var parser=new DOMParser();
                                                          var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlhttp.responseText,"text/html"); 

      }

 }
xmlhttp.open("GET",url, false);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Regards

Comment: why UI is reading backend file? can you request backend person to write a controller which reads the file and give response to UI

Comment: alert(xmlhttp.responseText)

Comment: normally the file content would be in the server response's body but it entirely depends on how the server is implemented

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) like this:

```js
fetch(url) // The default method is GET
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(text => {
    alert(text);
  });
```

The Fetch API is generally preferred over `XMLHttpRequest`, however, if you want to continue using XHR:

```js
const xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    alert(this.responseText);
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET",url, false);
xmlhttp.send();
```